# can't access to Youtube using the API using Php

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

so i'm making a site where to upload video.
I tried to implement the access to Youtube and to upload videos on YT from the site and is half working the videos get uploaded on phpmyadmin the table create the row but after that i just get an blank page instead of the authentification page of google for the access to YT.
Here is the code:

```
<?php

 require_once "Database_connection.php";
 require_once "Database_config.php";
 require_once "Database_class.php";
 require_once "Session.php";
  
 db = new DB;

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

$title = $_POST['Title'];
$description = $_POST['Description'];
$corso = trim($_POST['SceltaCorso']);
$tags = $_POST['tags'];
$privacy = !empty($_POST['privacy'])?$_POST['privacy']:'public';
/* al momento la variabile è disattivata perchè tutti i video verranno caricati su youtube però alcuni visibili altri privati
$youtube = trim($_POST['SceltaYoutube']);   
*/
/*limite modificato dalla configurazione vai su XAMPP riga APACHE tasto CONFIG e poi modifica 
  post_max_size = 40M; upload_max_filesize = 40M; (valori originali per ora sostituiti con 5G)*/
$maxsize = 42949672960;  //al momento la dimensione massima e di 5GB  

//if di controllo che sia stato inserito un file image con peso sotto i 5GB e gli si da le coordinate fino alla cartella di destinazione        
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {

    $name_img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $target_dir_img = "../img/Thumbnail_Video/";
    $target_file_img = $target_dir_img.$name_img;       

    if ($_FILES['image']['size'] >= $maxsize) {
        echo "Il file è troppo grande";
    }else{

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file_img);
    }

}elseif (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) == "false" ) {
    $target_file_img = "../img/Thumbnail_Video/logo_STM.png";
 } 
/*12/08/21 Provare a creare una tabella del database che raccolga dati solo temporaneamente per creare una anteprima del file da caricare (ES. tabella Video_Temp) */
//12/08/2021 Aggiungere la data di inserimento del file
if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != ''){
    // File upload path
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $filePath = "../Video/".$fileName;
    
    // Check the file type
    $allowedTypeArr = array("video/mp4", "video/avi", "video/mpeg", "video/mpg", "video/mov", "video/wmv", "video/rm");
    if(in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $allowedTypeArr)){
        // Upload file to local server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filePath)){
            // Insert video data in the database
            $vdata = array(
                'Title' => $title,
                'Description' => $description,
                'Tags' => $tags,
                'Privacy' => $privacy,
                'File_name' => $fileName
            );
            $insert = $db->insert($vdata);
            
            // Store db row id in the session
            $_SESSION['uploadedFileId'] = $insert;
        }else{
            header("Location:".BASE_URL."Video.php?err=ue");
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        header("Location:".BASE_URL."Video.php?err=fe");
        exit;
    }
}else{
    header('Location:'.BASE_URL.'Video.php?err=bf');
    exit;
}
}

 // Get uploaded video data from database
 $videoData = $db->getRow($_SESSION['uploadedFileId']);

 // Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
  $tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
   if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
 if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
die('The session state did not match.');
}

 $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
 $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
 header('Location: ' . REDIRECT_URL);
   }

 if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

  // Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
 if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
   
   try{
// REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
$videoPath = 'videos/'.$videoData['File_name'];

if(!empty($videoData['Youtube_video_id'])){
    // Uploaded video data
    $videoTitle = $videoData['Title'];
    $videoDesc = $videoData['Description'];
    $videoTags = $videoData['Tags'];
    $videoId = $videoData['Youtube_video_id'];
}else{
    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle($videoData['Title']);
    $snippet->setDescription($videoData['Description']);
    $snippet->setTags(explode(",", $videoData['Tags']));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = $videoData['Privacy'];

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);
    
    // Update youtube video id to database
    $db->update($videoData['Video_id'], $status['Video_id']);
    
    // Delete video file from local server
    @unlink("../Video/".$videoData['File_name']);
    
    // uploaded video data
    $videoTitle = $status['snippet']['Title'];
    $videoDesc = $status['snippet']['Description'];
    $videoTags = implode(",",$status['snippet']['Tags']);
    $videoId = $status['Video_id'];
}

// uploaded video embed html

$youtubeURL = 'https://youtu.be/'.$videoId;
$htmlBody .= "<p class='succ-msg'>Video Uploaded to YouTube</p>";
$htmlBody .= '<embed width="400" height="315" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoId.'"></embed>';
$htmlBody .= '<ul><li><b>YouTube URL: </b><a href="'.$youtubeURL.'">'.$youtubeURL.'</a></li>';
$htmlBody .= '<li><b>Title: </b>'.$videoTitle.'</li>';
$htmlBody .= '<li><b>Description: </b>'.$videoDesc.'</li>';
$htmlBody .= '<li><b>Tags: </b>'.$videoTags.'</li></ul>';
$htmlBody .= '<a href="../Php/Logout.php">Logout</a>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
   $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
 } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
   $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  $htmlBody .= 'Please reset session <a href="../Php/Logout.php">Logout</a>';
 }

  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
 } elseif (OAUTH_CLIENT_ID == '') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
 <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
 <p>
   You need to set <code>\$oauthClientID</code> and
   <code>\$oauthClientSecret</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
    END;
  } else {
    // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
  END;
  }
   ?>
```

i Think the problem is after this row:`$insert = $db->insert($vdata);` but i can't find it.
 Advice and suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot going on in your code and you should split it up in order to be able to debug your issue better.

This is the code i use for authorization.  Have a look at it.

[oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/YouTube%20Data%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>



require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){

    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}
```

[Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/YouTube%20Data%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
    /**
     * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
     * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
     * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
     *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
     * @return A google client object.
     */
    function getOauth2Client() {
        try {
            
            $client = buildClient();
            
            // Set the refresh token on the client. 
            if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
                $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
            }
            
            // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
            // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
            if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
                
                // Set the access token on the client.
                $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
                
                // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
                if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                    $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
                }           
                return $client; 
            } else {
                // We do not have access request access.
                header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Note: Your videos will all be private until your application has been thought the verification process.  So setting it public is over kill at this point.